# array formation and customization

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

```
[[9am-3pm,15,21,0],[3pm-9pm,21,23,1],[3pm-9pm,0,3,1],[9pm-3am,3,9,1]]
```

I have array like this which results on view

```
9am-3pm       0
3pm-9pm       1
3pm-9pm       1
9pm-3am       1
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
9am-3pm       0
3pm-9pm       2
9pm-3am       1
```

i.e 3pm-9pm is common so add and merge it into single.

any optimize solution ?

Comment: Your input is not valid ruby, your output is not valid ruby, you did not state the question and you violated rules of SP for how to ask questions.

Comment: Can you post an executable example or show some actual code, please? For example, how does that view look like and what's your actual data? (`9am-3pm` isn't a valid Ruby literal so you probably have something else, a string `"9am-3pm"` maybe?). And apart from that, are the middle elements relevant to the problem or just the first / last element of each sub-array?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Showing effort is very important. Did you research this? Why didn't that help? Did you write code? If no, why not, if yes, what is the minimal example that demonstrates the problem you had?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin instead giving a solution you're providing the irrelevant comment, you can find below answers which are working well, it is the valid Ruby syntax.

Comment: @Stefan yes you're right 9am-3pm is string  ("9am-3pm").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't shown anything you've done until now, there's really no optimization to give you.

For the expected output you can group your array by the first element, and then map that result into an array of arrays where the first element is the time-range ("Wxm-Yzm") and the second element is the sum of their last element (0, 1, 1, 1) correspondingly:

```
p [['9am-3pm',15,21,0],['3pm-9pm',21,23,1],['3pm-9pm',0,3,1],['9pm-3am',3,9,1]].group_by(&:first).map { |key, value| [key, value.sum(&:last)] }
# [["9am-3pm", 0], ["3pm-9pm", 2], ["9pm-3am", 1]]
```

Comment: you're solution is the one that I am looking for, Thanks a lot buddy

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [['9am-3pm',15,21,0],['3pm-9pm',21,23,1],
       ['3pm-9pm',0,3,1],['9pm-3am',3,9,1]]

h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(period,*),h| h[period] += 1 }
  #=> {"9am-3pm"=>1, "3pm-9pm"=>2, "9pm-3am"=>1}
```

You might want to just leave it a hash, but if you want the array shown in the question:

```
h.to_a
  #=> [["9am-3pm", 1], ["3pm-9pm", 2], ["9pm-3am", 1]]
```

See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument, referred to as the *default value*. This is sometimes called a *counting hash*.

Ruby's parser expands the expression `h[k] += 1` to

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

before evaluating it. If `h` does not have a key `k` this expression becomes

```
h[k] = 0 + 1
```

because `h[k]` on the right of the equality returns the default value, zero. Once `h` has a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right of the equality returns the current value of the key `k`.

Should you wonder why it's `h[k]` on the right side of the equality that returns the default value when `h` does not have a key `k`, recall that the expression `h[k] = h[k] + 1` is shorthand for

```
h.[]=(k, h.[](k) + 1)
```

which employs the the methods [Hash#[]=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) and [Hash#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D). It is the later method that returns the default value when evaluated with a value `k` that is not one of the hash's keys.